# Typescript Object Class members are defined with interface

Tags: angular, typescript

In Typescript, how do I define an Object Const, however make sure item members are in a interface?

**Currently have this:**

```
export const FrequencyType = {
  Weekly: { id: 1, code: 'Weekly', description: 'Weekly Description'},
  Annual: { id: 2, code: 'Annual', description: 'Annual Description'}
}
```

**Intended:**

with LookupVm Interface , this is giving error

```
export const FrequencyType = {
  Weekly: LookupVm: { id: 1, code: 'Weekly', description: 'Weekly Description'},
  Annual: LookupVm: { id: 2, code: 'Annual', description: 'Annual Description'}
}
```

**Reference:**

```
export interface LookupVm {
  id: number;
  code: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create interface like the below

```
export default interface LookupVm{
id:number,
code:string,
description: string
}
```

Then use it in the const like

```
export const FrequencyType :{
Weekly: LookupVm,
Annual: LookupVm
}= {
  Weekly: { id: 1, code: 'Weekly', description: 'Weekly Description'},
  Annual: { id: 2, code: 'Annual', description: 'Annual Description'}
}
```

Comment: I posted a solution, however I think your solution is better, thanks,

Comment: In order to allow any keys, you can use Record<string, LookupVm>

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, However Hitech solution will work also

```
export const FrequencyType = {
  Weekly: { 
    id: 1, 
    code: 'Weekly', 
    description: 'Weekly Description' 
  } as LookupVm,
  Annual: { 
    id: 2, 
    code: 'Annual', 
    description: 'Annual Description' 
  } as LookupVm
}
```